# Add a prefix column to an array

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

So I'm creating an export worksheet on my spreadsheet as I would like a consistent way to `VLOOKUP` using an `IMPORTRANGE` from this sheet. I have 3 datasets and I would like to add a prefix column to the export worksheet so I'm able `VLOOKUP` which dataset the data comes from. My initial though was to use this formula `={"Dataset 1", 'Dataset 1'!$A$2:$C6; "Dataset 2", 'Dataset 2'!$A$2:$C11; "Dataset 3", 'Dataset 3'!$A$2:$C16}` however I'm unable to use this because the strings I am adding aren't rows of data, I understand why I can't use this formula however I'm unsure how to accomplish what I'm trying to do here.

Here is an [example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WPzG0OsYifRTrZhp4ak3KzrCIHYGX5Jlb2dj6jZJEUo/edit?usp=sharing) with my desired outcome. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=arrayformula(query(
{
iferror(row('Dataset 1'!A:A)/0,"Dataset 1"),'Dataset 1'!A:C;
iferror(row('Dataset 2'!A2:A)/0,"Dataset 2"),'Dataset 2'!A2:C;
iferror(row('Dataset 3'!A2:A)/0,"Dataset 3"),'Dataset 3'!A2:C
},
"where Col2 is not null label Col1 'Dataset:'",1))
```

[image]

Alternatively, use FILTER:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({
    "Dataset:", "Name:", "ID:", "Apples:";
    IFERROR(FILTER('Dataset 1'!A2:A, 'Dataset 1'!A2:A <> "") / 0, "Dataset 1"), FILTER('Dataset 1'!A2:C, 'Dataset 1'!A2:A <> "");
    IFERROR(FILTER('Dataset 2'!A2:A, 'Dataset 2'!A2:A <> "") / 0, "Dataset 2"), FILTER('Dataset 2'!A2:C, 'Dataset 2'!A2:A <> "");
    IFERROR(FILTER('Dataset 3'!A2:A, 'Dataset 3'!A2:A <> "") / 0, "Dataset 3"), FILTER('Dataset 3'!A2:C, 'Dataset 3'!A2:A <> "")
})
```

If you want the blank rows to appear, use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({
    "Dataset:", "Name:", "ID:", "Apples:";
    IFERROR(row('Dataset 1'!A2:A) / 0, "Dataset 1"), 'Dataset 1'!A2:C;
    IFERROR(row('Dataset 2'!A2:A) / 0, "Dataset 2"), 'Dataset 2'!A2:C;
    IFERROR(row('Dataset 3'!A2:A) / 0, "Dataset 3"), 'Dataset 3'!A2:C
})
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the formula! I'm currently using the `FILTER` formula, I am having one problem with it however. When there is an empty row in one of the datasets the whole formula breaks. Do you know how to solve this issue?

Comment: There is a mismatch in the output of the `iferror` and the `filter`. I'll update the formula.